# creating relationship feeds through Amazon MWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

One of my client wants me to upload and maintain the variations of the products on Amazon. I am stuck in creating relationship(Variations) feed. I have googled it for many hours but with no luck.

I can easily generate and upload simple product, inventory, image and price feeds successfully through MWS, but my concept regarding variation feeds is not clear.

To simplify, my client has a product say "ABC" with two different colors (Black,Red). The ABC is not yet Registered on Amazon. The client has EAN for this product to list on amazon and also show the two different variations.

Now if any body can help me out as how to make the feeds to reflect the variations.

Please explain with practical code example.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

you can use following XML to create relationship.Use "_POST_PRODUCT_RELATIONSHIP_DATA_" as type of feed

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
<Header>
<DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
<MerchantIdentifier>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</MerchantIdentifier>
</Header>
<MessageType>Relationship</MessageType>
<Message>
<MessageID>1</MessageID>
<OperationType>Update</OperationType>
<Relationship>
    <ParentSKU>skt_parent1234</ParentSKU>
    <Relation>
       <SKU>skt_white123</SKU>
       <Type>Variation</Type>
    </Relation>
    <Relation>
        <SKU>skt_orange1234</SKU>
        <Type>Variation</Type>
    </Relation>
</Relationship>
</Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```